# Problema para encontrar directorio tmp en Linux Ubuntu, servidor remoto

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Estoy resolviendo unas pruebas de trabajo en un servidor Linux Ubuntu remoto, el problema es que no encuentro la carpeta tmp y necesito acceder a ella, agradezco cualquier ayuda.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es una pregunta de programación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas `tmp`, eso significa `tmp` dentro del directorio en el que estás. Si quieres ver `/tmp` tienes que especificar `/tmp` o usar `tmp` estando ya en el directorio `/`. En el ejemplo que colocas estas trabajando desde el home del usuario, como es root, probablemente estas en `/root`.... y te está diciendo que `/root/tmp` no existe.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta me ayudó mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Lo logré, paso el procedimiento explicado por si alguien tiene la misma duda.
cd my_school (Entro al directorio my_school) 
ls (Mostrar contenido, verifico que esté el achivo hello_world) 
cp hello_world /tmp (copio hello_world desde my_school a tmp que está en root) 
cd (salgo de my_school)
cd /tmp (entro al directorio tmp que está en root)
ls (Mostrar contenido, verifico que esté el achivo hello_world)